# Pandas: divide dataframe by some values in column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have dataframe

```
date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  audi    a6  1
2016-02 abakan  bmw 5-series    2
2016-02 abakan  bmw x5  2
2016-02 abakan  chery   a15 1
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   3
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   10
```

I need to divide it to more little dataframes to using `linear regression` from `sklearn`. Is any way to do this or there is some way to specify it `linear regression` to consider different values in columns?

```
date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  audi    a6  1

date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  bmw 5-series    2

date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  bmw x5  2

date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  chery   a15 1

date    city    brand   model   count
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   3
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   10
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.goupby('brand').get_group('name of the group')`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas solution is with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `list comprehension` - output is list of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = [g for i, g in df.groupby(['date','city','brand','model'])]
print (dfs)
[      date    city brand model  count
0  2016-02  abakan  audi    a6      1,       date    city brand     model  count
1  2016-02  abakan   bmw  5-series      2,       date    city brand model  count
2  2016-02  abakan   bmw    x5      2,       date    city  brand model  count
3  2016-02  abakan  chery   a15      1,       date    city      brand  model  count
4  2016-02  abakan  chevrolet  cruze      3
5  2016-02  abakan  chevrolet  cruze     10]

print (dfs[0])
      date    city brand model  count
0  2016-02  abakan  audi    a6      1
```

Comment: I think yes, it depends of output. If need list of `df` or need `df1`, `df2`, `dfn`...